# What process would add gdiplus.dll and msdia80.dll at the root of a hard disk

Tags: windows, file-system, process

I added a new 4TB hard disk drive to my desktop computer, and noticed a couple of days later two .dll files at the root of the drive.

The environment in question is a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional (American English, if that matters). This new hard disk does not contain the OS (the OS is on a separate SSD disk). I have not installed any applications to this new hard disk.

Being that the OS is on a separate disk, what would be the reason for some process to place dll files on the root of the new HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are commonly the artifact of installing the Visual C++ redistributable package, often installed with many applications and video games. It's worth noting that Steam installs this package with a large number of games.

Some more info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927665